# extract the value of a variable subset whose name is built in a for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to transfer the content of a variable whose name is built on a for loop model to an intermediate object in R without success :

```
my_list <- list(first = "un", second = "deux", third = "trois")
my_vect <- c("first","second","third")
for(i in my_vect){intermediate <- get(paste("my_list$",i,sep=""))}
```

> Error in get(paste("my_list$", i, sep = "")) : 
>     object 'my_list$first' not found**

```
my_list$first 
[1] "un"
```

How come R can't find the object `my_list$first` which seems to be obviously present and evaluate to `un` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just use `[[` instead of `$`

```
my_list[[my_vect[1]]]
#[1] "un"
```

Using `for` loop

```
out <- vector('list', length(my_vect))
for(i in seq_along(my_vect)) out[[i]] <- my_list[[my_vect[i]]]
```

or to subset based on the whole 'my_vect'

```
my_list[my_vect]
```

Comment: Thanks but then it is not in a for / loop model ... thereafter i would like to use the variable "intermediate" as an argument to predict a linear model actually... so I need the value to be transfered in the loop

Comment: @kgluborg  I also updated with a `for` loop please check

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, It solves it :

```
out <- vector('list', length(my_vect))
for(i in seq_along(my_vect)) out[[i]] <- my_list[[my_vect[i]]]
out

#[[1]]
#[1] "un"

#[[2]]
#[1] "deux"

#[[3]]
#[1] "trois"

for(i in seq_along(my_vect)) out <- my_list[[my_vect[i]]]
out

#[1] "trois"
```

I actually just want to capture a part of it with a fixed name ... cheers :)

Comment: just out io out [[i]] ... sorry if it is inappropriate just want to thank you